# jQuery menu function error

Tags: jquery, menu

I have this menu which isn't made by me. http://jsfiddle.net/LQzpN/

It works fine apart from the fact that is reports a JavaScript error.

I've checked it on [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQzpN/) but cant figure out how to fix the error.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Click on the `JSLint` button on the menu bar of jsfiddle. This may give you some tips

Comment: What error do you get? Without the HTML accompanying this javascript, it's not easy to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: This comes from jFiddle console :Error:

Problem at line 21 character 28: 'toArray' was used before it was defined.

function toArray(strg){

Implied global: toArray 10,12, jQuery 30

Unused variable: toArray 7 "backgroundPosition"

Answer (score 0):

toArray is a "reserved" word from jQuery 1.4 and up, change it to something else, then it should work.